# Audio output front and back jack ubuntu 17.10

Tags: sound, speakers, headset, output

I have front and back audio output jacks on my pc. When I plug in my headset to the front jack, audio output line disappears from sound settings and it shows only headphones. I want to switch between headphones and speakers without unplugging the headset all the time. Please help me I am new with linux.

Comment: It depends on your front-panel. I think it is impossible with older `AC'97`-front-panels, it is a question of the electronic circuit. With newer `IntelHD Audio`-front-panel it should be possible, but I've only old `AC'97`-front-panel, so I can not test anything. Also one difference between the two standards is that with an `IntelHD Audio`-front-panel we can retask the Jacks (we can choose if we want that jack used as input or output), this is not possible with old `AC'97`-front-panels.

Comment: @mook765 I don't know what AC' 97 front panel is. I am not very good with tech. All I know is that it worked fine in windows 10 and linux mint 18.2

Answer (score 1):

If you only want one audio output for playback

go to Pulseaudio Volume Control, Playback tab. 

A drop-down menu will display choices for switching audio output

If your sound device will support having both audio outputs:

Run `alsamixer` in terminal and find playback settings (F3) for correct sound card (F6) 

Use left and right arrow keys to find "auto-mute" option

Up and down arrow keys change setting between disabled and enabled

Answer (score 0):

Make 2 scripts, like below, and run them to switch between headphone and speaker. Also, it would fail if you use gnome-volume controls to modify volume. This thing works purely from command line. You can change volume by fidgeting with percentage value in `amixer set Master playback 80% unmute`

1. Speaker_on.sh

   ```
   amixer set "Headphone" playback 0% unmute
   amixer set Master playback 80% unmute
   amixer set "Speaker" playback 100% unmute
   ```
2. Headphone_on.sh

   ```
   amixer set "Speaker" playback 0% mute
   amixer set Master playback 80% unmute
   amixer set "Headphone" playback 100% unmute
   ```

Comment: You can make a short script to increase and decrease volume using `amixer set Master playback 80% unmute` and assign it to keyboard short-cuts for ease. Also, `Speaker_on.sh`  and `Headphone_on.sh` can be assigned to keyboard shortcuts.